# Get child ID and add to parent as ARIA attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, wai-aria

I have a number of images and captions on a page, set up in `<figure><img><figcaption>` groups. I'd like to use JavaScript (or jQuery) to grab the ID of the `figcaption` and add an '`aria-labelledby`' attribute to the parent `<figure>`.

For example, I have the following (simplified):

```
<figure id="figure1">
    <img src="x.jpg">
    <figcaption id="caption1">Sample</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure id="figure2">
    <img src="y.jpg">
    <figcaption id="caption2">Sample</figcaption>
</figure>
```

How can I loop through each  element and add the appropriate 'aria-labelledby' attribute, e.g., `aria-labelledby="caption1"`?

I tried this but getting an undefined function error:

```
$('figure').attr('aria-labelledby', function() {
    $(this).find('figcaption').attr('id');
})
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to add ARIA here - are you running into a specific problem without it? Generally speaking, you only need to add ARIA where the original HTML doesn't already capture the meaning you want. So, for example, there's no need to use aria-labelledby on an INPUT that already has a LABEL associated with it - this would seem to be a similar case.

Comment: I assumed it would add value, but is the relationship already implicitly stated by the image and figcaption being inside the figure element? Could I also stop doing similar for details and summary elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` that value, otherwise you're not doing anything with it.

```
$('figure').attr('aria-labelledby', function() {
    return $(this).find('figcaption').attr('id');
})
```

Demo

```js
$('figure').attr('aria-labelledby', function() {
  return $(this).find('figcaption').attr('id');
})
```

```css
[aria-labelledby] {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="figure1">
    <img src="x.jpg">
    <figcaption id="caption1">Sample</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure id="figure2">
    <img src="y.jpg">
    <figcaption id="caption2">Sample</figcaption>
</figure>
```